# C program to find positive integers with beautiful property

Tags: c, numbers, double, number-theory

I made a C program to search for positive integers that has this kind of property:

[image]

So clearly I want the program to at least output the number `262144`, but my program does not output this. And also `1`  has this property, and my program does output this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long double digitspow(long int num){

   char numstr[30];

   sprintf(numstr,"%ld",num);   

   int n=strlen(numstr);
   int digits[n];
   long int total=((int) numstr[0])-48;

   for (int i=1; i<n;i++){
            
            digits[i]=((int) numstr[i])-48;
            total=pow(total,digits[i]);
            
   }
   return sqrt(total);

}

int main()
{

long int num;


for (int i=1;i<20000000;i++){

   num=i;
   if (abs(num - digitspow(num))<0.0000001){
    printf("%ld\n",num);
   }

}
```

Comment: My calculator doesn't output the left side from the right, either. Why is it clear that your program should?

Comment: @WeatherVane: For mathematicians, exponentiation right associates.

Comment: When you modify your program to test only 262144 and follow every step in it, printing the results of all calculations using `printf` or using a debugger to see them, where does it first go wrong?

Comment: For 262,144 to qualify, the exponentiation must right associate. Your program calculates the expression with left association.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes I just realize mistake in how I compute the powers...

Comment: Which means that the processing can stop at the first 0 or 1 in the number, since 0 or 1 raised to any power is 0 or 1 respectively. For example, computing `2^6^2^1^4^4` can be simplified to `2^6^2`.

Comment: I modified your test program to use 128 bit numbers (with a bit of effort ;-). AFAICT, for 262144, applying the last 4 exceeds a 128 bit number. The number of bits required is `6 * 2 * 1 * 4 * 4` which is 192 bits. So, either the `sqrt` has to be applied on _each_ subterm [which I think is just incorrect] or you'll need arbitrary precision math (e.g.) https://gmplib.org/

Comment: @CraigEstey: Not sure what you mean, 1^4^4 = 1, so 2^6^2^1^4^4 =68719476736, a 37 bit integer.

Comment: Whether you calculate it as `2*(6^(2^(1^(4^4))))` or as `((((2^6)^2)^1)^4)^4` it does NOT come out to be `262144`

Comment: @SGeorgiades: You're forgetting the square root.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk This is the progression I get: `n=6 numstr='262144' d[0]=2 d[1]=6 in=2 in^d=64 d[2]=2 in=64 in^d=4096 d[3]=1 in=4096 in^d=4096 d[4]=4 in=4096 in^d=281474976710656 d[5]=4 in=281474976710656 in^d=6277101735386680763835789423207666416102355444464034512896`

Comment: @CraigEstey [Here's an example of exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#A_detailed_example) as a **right associative** operator.

Comment: @user3386109 Ah, that might be it. (I've never done w^x^y^z in C and just riffed off OP's original code). C doesn't have an exponentation operator, so I was unaware of its right associativity. I'll adjust and retry.

Comment: @CraigEstey It's so rare to have multiple levels of exponentiation that I'm not sure that everybody agrees on how it should associate, and parentheses are the safest way to go. In this instance, right association gives the correct answer: `2^6^2^1^4^4 = 2^6^2^1^256 = 2^6^2^1 = 2^36` and `sqrt(2^36) = 2^18 = 262144`.

Comment: @user3386109 [Pure] mathematicians probably have this figured out [I would defer ...] but it's been quite a while since my pure math days (sigh ;-). I got a version to work with right associativity. The sequence you just posted makes me think of a possible cheat to bypass the `sqrt`: Leave off `digits[0]` (aka `d0` aka 2) and have `total` as 36. To get `sqrt`, it's `d0 ^ (total / 2)` and [maybe] `total` must be divisible by 2. It's late here so my mind is getting foggy. I'm coding this but my IRL/GF says I must stop _now_ ;-) Does this idea seem feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The mistake is in the way I compute the exponent, the program was computing, for example if `num=262144`, this `(((((2^6)^2)^1)^4)^4)` instead of `2^(6^(2^(1^(4^(4)))))`.
So here is a solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long double digitspow(long long int num){

   char numstr[30];

   sprintf(numstr,"%ld",num);   

   long int n=strlen(numstr);
   int digits[n];
   long long int total=((int) numstr[n-1])-48;
   
//computing exponent here:
//
   for (int i=n-2; i>=0;i--){
            
            digits[i]=((int) numstr[i])-48;
            total=pow(digits[i], total);
            
   }
//
   return sqrt(total);

}

int main()
{

long long int num;


for (long long int i=1;i<262200;i++){

   num=i;
   if (abs(num - digitspow(num))<0.0000001){
    printf("%lld\n",num);
    printf("%lf\n",digitspow(num));
   }

}
}
```

Comment: Is this your _real_ code? It is missing `#include <math.h>` And, when I add that I get a lot of prints of `-nan`

Comment: @CraigEstey i didnt get an error using Cxx app in androud.

Comment: This matches on 1, 2, 55, 262144. 55 is wrong because the `sqrt` returns `55.901699`. For a given _single_ digit `x`, I think one should interpret this as `x^1` and should _not_ match on 2. You have a bug that interprets `x` as `x^x` and `2` becomes `2^2`